# Python DF2Gspread library can not save a DF to Google sheet

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Every sheet works fine in DF2Gspread except for [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fdBDJOeR_to-R2xToFm_YIAo97EKzl5x/view?usp=sharing).

This is my code in **GDriveScript.py**:

```
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
import pandas as pd


def save_to_drive(df, spreadsheet, wks_name):
    d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet, wks_name)
```

and **Run.py**:

```
from GDriveScript import save_to_drive
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('/path/December_2018_Primary.xlsx', index_col=0)
print(df)

# Export to drive


spreadsheet = '1YIDmA1U***'

wks_name = 'Test Sheet'

save_to_drive(df, spreadsheet, wks_name)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 3):

`df.reset_index()` will solve the problem.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, caused by at least two identical entries in the indexing column. Since I do not know the entries in your index column  I'm not sure if you have the same cause like me.
After getting all those entries unique it worked for me.